# Regex expression to get the file name

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract only  filename from the complete file name + time stamp  . below is the input.

```
    String filePath = "fileName1_20150108.csv";
```

expected output should be:      "**fileName1**"

```
    String filePath2 = "fileName1_filedesc1_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv"
```

And expected output should be:      "**fileName1_filedesc1**"

I wrote a below code in java to get the file name but it is working for first part (filePath) but not for filepath2.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*.(?=_)");
        String filePath = "fileName1_20150108.csv";
        String filePath2 = "fileName1_filedesc1_20150108_002_20150109013841.csv";
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filePath);
         while (matcher.find()) {
              System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
              System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
              System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
```

Can somebody please help me to correct the regex so i can parse both filepath using same regex?
Thanks

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the language you're using, so that you'll get answers from people who know that language, and not waste the time of people who don't.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor the start, and make the `.*` non-greedy:

```
^.*?(_\D.*?)?(?=[_.])
```

Update: change the second group (for `fileDesc`) to optional, and enforce that it starts with a non-digit character. This will work as long as your `fileDesc` strings never start with numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working for above scenario but it is not working for **String filePath = "fileName1_20150108.csv"**;

Comment: @code1234 Just add `.` to the terminating lookahead; see my edit.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you changed your question. See further edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the characters before the first underscode, the first underscore, and then the characters until the next underscore:

```
^[^_]*_[^_]*
```

Comment: this doesn't match the name as he's requested

Comment: @Hooman: It matches the file name as the question was stated when the answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `"^(.*?)_([0-9_]*)\\.([^.]*)$"`

It will return you 3 groups:

- the base name (assuming not a single part will be all numbers)
- the timestamp info
- the extension.

You can test here: http://fiddle.re/v0hne6 (RegexPlanet)